# Ruby, how to control the return value of calling an instanciated object

Tags: ruby

If I do this:

```
class PseudoRelationship
    def my_method(args)
         args
    end
end

a = PseudoRelationship.new
```

I got as output

```
x
#<PseudoRelationship:0x109c2ebb0>
```

I would like it to behave like a Enumerator or Array, so I get for example this output

```
x = PseudoRelationship.new [1,2,3]
x
[1,2,3]
```

Pd. This is not for rails.

What I'm trying to do is behave like an array.

Its something that rails 2.3 seems to use, for example, you can do

```
my_model.relationship # returns an array
my_model.relationship.find #is a method
```

I'm trying to replicate that behaviour.

Comment: Out of curiosity, *why* do you want that result from instantiating an object to be what you pass in? Also if you want it to behave like an an Enumerator or Array, why not inherit from Array or include Enumerable? [A useful article for including Enumerable](http://kconrails.com/2010/11/30/ruby-enumerable-primer-part-1-the-basics/).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I added an answer, but while it achieves the output you want, I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for. Please comment on the answer if it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jholtrop was close, you want to overwrite the `inspect` method

```
2.0.0p645> 
class PseudoRelationship
    def initialize(args)
        @args = args
    end

    def inspect
        @args.inspect
    end
end

2.0.0p645> PseudoRelationship.new [2, 3, 5]                                                                                                                                                                 
[2, 3, 5]
```

--Edit based on OP's reasons for *wanting* this behavior--

While the above class displays *what we want to see* in the console, it doesn't actually assume any management of args in a way that treats `args` as an Enumerable. The OP's inspiration is drawn from a Rails construct, the `ActiveRecord::Relation`*. To imulate that style of behavior, you have to include Enumerable.

```
class PseudoRelationship
    include Enumerable

    def initialize(args)
        @args = args
    end

    def each(&block)
       @args.each(&block)
    end

    def inspect
        @args.inspect
    end

    # Add extra functions to operate on @args
    # This is obviously a silly example
    def foo?
      @args.include? :foo
    end

    def [](key)
      @args[key]
    end

    def last
      @args[-1]
    end
end


2.0.0p645> PseudoRelationship.new [2, 3, 5]                                                                                                                                                                 
[2, 3, 5]
2.0.0p645> x = PseudoRelationship.new [2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5]
2.0.0p645> x.each 
#<Enumerator: [2, 3, 5]:each>
2.0.0p645> x.each_with_index
#<Enumerator: [2, 3, 5]:each_with_index>
2.0.0p645> x.each_with_index { |e, i| puts "#{i} => #{e}" }
0 => 2
1 => 3
2 => 5
[2, 3, 5]
2.0.0p645> x.foo?
false
2.0.0p645> x.first
2
2.0.0p645> x.last
5
2.0.0p645> x[1]
3
2.0.0p645> x[5]
nil
2.0.0p645> x
[2, 3, 5]
```

* This construct wasn't explictly stated, but I'm assuming based on the context

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much, one question, if I want methods like first, last, [], do I need to define them? or ruby has another module that add that functionality.

Comment: Nope (kinda). Using the class above with console example: `x.frist #=> 2`, but you'll have to make methods like `#last` and define the index accessor `[]`

Comment: @ArnoldRoa added the methods for you ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you want the variable `x` to equal the arguments passed when instantiating the object, you need to add an `initialize` method to your class. Something like this should work:

```ruby
class PseudoRelationship
  def initialize(args)
    args
  end

  def my_method(args)
    args
  end
end

x = PseudoRelationship.new [1, 2, 3]
x == [1, 2, 3] #=> true
```

EDIT:

Yes, the above won't work, really. If you want it to behave like an array, you could inherit from `Array`, but that can lead to strange issues and is generally not recommended. However, the below would work:

```ruby
class PseudoRelationship < Array
end

x = PseudoRelationship.new [1, 2, 3]
x.class #=> PseudoRelationship < Array
x == [1, 2, 3] #=> true
```

Comment: Nop, it returns false, and x is #<PseudoRelationship:0x1099463f8> not [1,2,3]

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are asking to alter the "representation" of the object, not the "return value." To give the object a new String representation, you can define the #to_s method on the class. For example:

```
class PseudoRelationship
  def initialize(v)
    @v = v
  end

  def to_s
    @v.to_s
  end
end
```

Then in irb, for example:

```
1.9.3-p551 :021 > x = PseudoRelationship.new [:a, 42, false]
 => [:a, 42, false]
```

Comment: Nope, this return the object an instance of the object `#<PseudoRelationship:0x09908fwef09 @v= [:a,42,false]>`